# Sorting Gridview with data from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have been trying to get this to sort but all the code examples I have seen don't seem to work. Is it possible to sort the data in my GridView? I have posted my markup code and the code behind code that populates the table.

Any help would be great :D even better if somebody can show me how and explain it so I know for future (and maybe somebody else will gain from this in the future)

**Mark-up**

```
<asp:GridView ID="_propertyGridView" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="PropertyRowCommand"  Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Ref" SortExpression="Id" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PostCode" HeaderText="Post Code" SortExpression="PostCode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractsFinishedOn" HeaderText="Contract Signed On" SortExpression="ContractsFinishedOn" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile" HeaderText="Mobile No." SortExpression="Mobile" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LandLordEmail" HeaderText="Owners Email" SortExpression="LandLordEmail" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MoveInDate" HeaderText="Move In Date" SortExpression="MoveInDate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="_tenantPaymentCheckBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Bind("TenantReceipt") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="_tenantPaymentLink" Text="Send Tenant Receipt" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Id") %>' CommandName="TenantEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('This will email &amp; sms the tenant, please make sure its correct');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="_landlordInfoCheckBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Bind("LandlordInfo") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="_landlordInfoLink" Text="Request Landlord Info" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Id") %>' CommandName="LandlordInfoEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('This will email &amp; sms the landlord, please make sure its correct');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status3">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:CheckBox ID="_landlordRentCheckBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Bind("LandlordReceipt") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="_landlordRentLink" Text="Send Landlord Receipt" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Id") %>' CommandName="LandlordEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('This will email &amp; sms the landlord, please make sure its correct');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**How the GridView is populated with data**

```
protected void GetProperties()
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AgentGetPropertiesToFinish", conn);
   cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   SqlDataReader rdr;

   conn.Open();
   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   _propertyGridView.DataSource = rdr;
   _propertyGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You could sort it in the Stored Procedure too by adding `Order By` statement at the end

Comment: IF you want to sort from the ui, follow this sample http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/gridview-sorting-example-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1082.aspx

Comment: I tried the one on dotnetfox.com but didnt know how to adapt it to my code

Comment: Sort with which column from datasoure i.e. Id,PostCode..?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link to convert your *datareader* to *datatable*.

```
datatable dt=new datatable();
dt.load(dr);
```

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=143

After that:

```
gridview.datasource=dt;
```

as above answer states use

`dt.DefaultView.sort="columnname direction"` from sorting event.

Sorting event will get you current sortdirection of a column so decide current direction of sort based on that.

So in your sorting event:

```
dt.DefaultView.sort="columnA ASC";
gridview.DataSource=dt;
gridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: almost worked but got this error "An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code" how do i find out the column names? i thought if i defined the names in the markup code then the sort expression would be the column name

Additional information: Cannot find column Id"

Comment: dt.DefaultView.sort="columnA ASC"; i cahnged columnA to FirstName because that is the name of the column (i hope) i even tried e.sortexpression but both trow the error

Comment: sorry i dont understand what your asking me to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this to sort with `PostCode`:

```
    protected void GetProperties()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AgentGetPropertiesToFinish", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        conn.Open();

        adp.Fill(table);

        _propertyGridView.DataSource = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(a => a.Field<string>("PostCode"));
        _propertyGridView.DataBind();
    }
```